# Is my proof of "Fixed $\epsilon>0$, $f$ periodic of period $T$ for all $T\in(0,\epsilon]$ implies $f$ constant" correct?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Problem: "Let $\epsilon>0$ fixed. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a periodic function with period $T$ for all $T\in(0,\epsilon]$, that is for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for any $T\in(0,\epsilon]$ it is $f(x+T)=f(x)$. Show that $f$ is constant."

I've tried this: consider the two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$.

For $x>0$: by hypothesis the identity $f(x+T)=f(x)$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for any $T\in(0,\epsilon]$, so using it with $x=\epsilon$ and $T=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ I get that $f(\epsilon)=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\epsilon\right)$. Since $\epsilon \ne 0$, it is $\epsilon \ne \frac{3}{2}\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$ and so $f$ assumes the same value on the two different points $x=\epsilon$ and $x=\frac{3}{2}\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the identity $f(\epsilon)=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\epsilon\right)$ holds for any $\epsilon>0$; this means that $f$ is constant for $x>0$, because it has the same value for two different generic points in intervals that, if I take the unions, become the entire positive half-real line $(0,\infty)$.

Since $\epsilon>0$, it is $-\epsilon<0$ and so considering $x=-\epsilon$ and $T=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ it is $f(-\epsilon)=f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\right)$ and hence $f$ is constant for $x<0$ too, using the same reasoning for $x>0$. So, in conclusion, $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this correct? I'm not sure about the part when I say

> Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the identity $f(\epsilon)=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\epsilon\right)$ holds for any $\epsilon>0$; this means that $f$ is constant for $x>0$

Because technically $\epsilon$ is fixed, so I can only deduce that $f$ is constant in the points $\epsilon$ and $\frac{3}{2}\epsilon$; maybe I should let $x$ and $T$ vary and deduce that $f$ is constant in the interval $[x,x+\epsilon]$ and extend it to $\mathbb{R}$, but then I don't get why the reasoning of some proofs in which they consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and concludes that the result holds for all $\epsilon>0$ (because that worked for a generic $\epsilon>0$) is correct. Could this not work here because it is expressely said that $\epsilon$ is fixed?

Comment: $\varepsilon $ is not arbitrary but fixed. Also, you seem to do very complicated. Since $f(T)=f(0)$ for all $T\in (0,\varepsilon ]$, then $f$ is constant on $ (0,\varepsilon ]$, and by periodicity, $f$ is constant on all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This is actually trivial. The condition tells you explicitly that $f$ is constant on **each** interval of length $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. $\epsilon$ and $\frac {2\epsilon} 3$ are not generic points; they are related to each other with a fixed ratio between them.

Let $x<y$. There exists a positive integer $n$ such that $T\equiv\frac {y-x}n \in (0,\epsilon]$. By iteration of $f(x+T)=f(x)$we get $f(x+nT)=f(x)$. Hence, $f(y)=f(nT+x)=f(x)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, two questions: i) the fact that there is a fixed ratio causes a wrong reasoning because the existence of this ratio doesn't allow me to describe all the generic points, but only the ones that satisfy that ratio?
ii) the existence of $n$ such that $\frac{y-x}{n} \in (0,\epsilon]$ is because $\frac{y-x}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and so there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{y-x}{n}\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\right]$ for $n\ge n_0$? $n$ depends on $x$ and $y$, right?

Comment: YES and YES. Both are correct. @Sonozaki